# Laravel query builder - Select elements unique or null on specific column

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a model `Form` for table forms. There is a column called `guid` which can be null, or contain some sort of grouping random hash.

I need to select all forms that have column `guid` either null or unique in current search. In other words, for repeating `guid` values in current search I select only first occurence of every guid hash.

I tried:

```
$results = App\Form::where(... some where clauses .. ).groupBy('guid')
```

and it's almost ok, but for all rows, where `guid == NULL` it groups them and selects only one (and I need all of them).

How can I get the unique or null rows either by building proper SQL query or filtering the results in PHP?

**Note:** I need my `$results` to be an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` instance

**EDIT:**

I fount out that SQL version of query I need is:

```
SELECT * FROM `forms` WHERE .... GROUP BY IFNULL(guid, id)
```

What would be equivallent query for Laravel's database query builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your edited question, you can use [`raw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#raw-expressions) as;

```
->groupBy(DB::raw("IFNULL('guid', 'id')"))
```

So your final query will be as:

```
$results = App\Form::where(... some where clauses .. )
                   ->groupBy(DB::raw("IFNULL('guid', 'id')"));
```

By above query, your `$results` will be an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.

Comment: Yes, that's it. And it's still `Builder` instance - that's what I was looking for! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE: Using `DB::raw`**

```
App\Form::where(... conditions ...)
        ->groupBy(DB::raw("IFNULL('guid', 'id')"));
```

Or the another way could be:

You can also use [`whereNotNull`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereNotNull), [`whereNull`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereNull) & at last merge both the collections using [`merge()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-merge) like this:

First get the results where `guid` is grouped by (excluding null guid's here):

```
$unique_guid_without_null = App\Form::whereNotNull('guid')->groupBy('guid')->get();
```

Now, get the results where `guid` is `null`:

```
$all_guid_with_null = App\Form::whereNull('guid')->get();
```

and at last merge both the collections using `merge()` method:

```
$filtered_collection = $unique_guid_without_null->merge($all_guid_with_null);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I cannot use `get()` and `merge()` - I need the `$result` to be query builder `Builder` instance

Comment: But you've mentioned that - either by using query or using php, so `get()` and `merge()` are php methods!

Comment: @Gacek - Why you removed my accepted answer? I've answered it correect on your request!

Comment: Because you used `get()` at the end and thus it's no longer `Builder` instance

Comment: @Gacek - So you can also say that the another person doesn't mentioned other stuffs that i mentioned. :( Its unfair, let it be, no fight, this world is less of loyal people!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Up-voting this one.